# how to efficiently search for subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model :

```
var couponschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    couponcode: String
});

var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    coupons: [couponschema]
});
```

I need to find and remove all coupons with a particular `coupon code`.

I could not find any mongoose query to *batch delete multiple subdocuments accross multiple documents*. I am therefore left with iterating through each `user` document, then looping through `coupon` subdocs to see if there's a matching coupon, and then deleting them - but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

So please suggest a clean way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it'll give you an idea (using [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)):

```
db.user.update(
  { },
  { 
    $pull : {
      "coupons" : <...expression here...> // match specific coupons
    }
  }, 
  { multi: true }
)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
tUser.update({
  'coupons.couponcode': data.regid 
}, { 
  $pull: {
    coupons: {
       couponcode: data.regid
    }
  }
}, { multi: true, safe: true }, function (err, val) { 
  // .. do something here
});
```

Mongoose `update` API [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update).

Comment: Hey... that worked perfectly... this is the actual code that I wrote... please add this to your answer and I will accept : `tUser.update({'coupons.couponcode': data.regid }, 
{ $pull: {coupons: {'coupons.couponcode':data.regid }}}, 
{ multi: true, safe: true }
function (err,val) { });`

Comment: and [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) link helped too.